# Accessing structured data types in numba vs. numpy

Tags: python, numpy, types, numba

I’ve noticed a discrepancy between how `numba` and `numpy` allow access to the different sub-fields of arrays with structured datatypes. I’m testing the following definitions of a few functions accessing sub-fields and an array `a`:

```
import numba
import numpy

@numba.njit
def func_numba(a):
    return a[5].field0

def func_numpy(a):
    return a[5].field0

def func_numpy_recarray(a):
    return numpy.rec.array(a)[5].field0

a = numpy.zeros(10, dtype=[('field0', 'i4'), ('field1', 'f8')])
a['field0'] = numpy.arange(10)
# array([(0, 0.), (1, 0.), (2, 0.), (3, 0.), (4, 0.), (5, 0.), (6, 0.),
#        (7, 0.), (8, 0.), (9, 0.)],
#       dtype=[('field0', '<i4'), ('field1', '<f8')])
```

Calling the different functions shows that the version `func_numba` works, even though the “normal” version of the same function does not:

```
func_numba(a)
# 5
func_numpy(a)
# AttributeError: 'numpy.void' object has no attribute 'field0'
func_numpy_recarray(a)
# 5
```

The option of accessing sub-fields through attributes is usually only provided by `numpy` record arrays, as exemplified by the function `func_numpy_recarray`, so I’m assuming `numba` has some kind of separate representation of `numpy` arrays with different operations defined for them. Unfortunately, it’s not so easy to inspect an object’s type or properties within `numba` JIT functions.

Is this an intentional difference between `numba` and ordinary `numpy` and what is the preferred way of accessing structured datatypes in `numba`?

I’m using `numba` version 0.48.0.

Comment: `recarray` is a subclass of `ndarray`, one that overrides the `__getattribute__` to accept field names as attributes.  That method code is Python which you can read for yourself.  I think `recarray` is a something relic from the past, currently coded as a thin subclass layer on top of the more basic structured array.  `numba` is newer, and appears to implement that record attribute functionality without adding the subclassing layer.

Comment: The main area of development in `numpy` structured arrays is in the handling of multi-field indexing.  See release notes in for the past several versions.  It appears that `numba` does not implement this.  Try `a[['field0']]` with and without `numba`.

Comment: @hpaulj I’m aware of the status of `recarray`; I’m more concerned about the differences of the `numba` API (compared to `numpy`) and which parts of it can be expected to be stable.